# Find a matrix whose nullspace is spanned by the vectors $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,1,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm no expert at linear agebra, but I have a feeling I made a paper with an impossible question. The question, as stated in the title is:

$V$ is a vector space spanned by the vectors $\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Find a matrix ${\bf B}$ that has $V$ as its null space.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider matrices with only one row. If the $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$, is a matrix with the desired property, then we must have $a+b+c=0$ and $2a+b=0$. This is an underdetermined system, and so has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$ I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how a nullspace with at least 2 dimentions can have a vector without zero somewhere in it. Using what William said a matrix [-1 2 -1] nets a nullspace of

[2,1,0];[-1,0,1] Which isn't V. or is it?

Comment: That's exactly what I got. I was able to prove that [2,1,0];[-1,0,1] is a basis of V. (Unless I made a mistake somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that you are working in $\mathbf{R}^3$ then you can extend the list 
$(1,1,1),(2,1,0)$ to yield the basis $\beta = (1,1,1),(2,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Then with the respect to this basis if you define the the linear map $T:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ as follows

$$T\left(c_1(1,1,1)+c_2(2,1,0)+c_3(0,0,1)\right) = c_3(0,0,1)$$ then the matrix of such a map 
$$[T]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
will have its null space spanned by the column vectors that you mentioned.